# Visual Studio builds module but Webpack fails with "Module not found"

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs, typescript, webpack, visual-studio-2017

I'm importing a custom module like this in a `.tsx` file:

```
import { LinkContainer } from './typings/LinkContainer';
```

Visual Studio builds without a problem but when I try to run `webpack` I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./Features/Menu/Menu.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './typings/LinkContainer' in 'C:\Users\<user>\Documents\<solution>\<project>\Features\Menu'
 @ ./Features/Menu/Menu.tsx 19:22-56
 @ ./Features/App.tsx
 @ ./Features/index.tsx
 @ multi react-hot-loader/patch ./Features/index.tsx
```

File content for `LinkContainer.d.ts`:

```
import { ComponentClass } from "react";
import { NavLinkProps } from "react-router-dom";

type LinkContainer = ComponentClass<NavLinkProps>;
export const LinkContainer: LinkContainer;
```

Comment: Have you tried including the extension in the import statement, e.g. `import { LinkContainer } from './typings/LinkContainer.tsx';`

Comment: @Jayce444 The problem I'm having is that this is not my module, it is a module downloaded from `npm`, `react-router-bootstrap`, located in `node_modules\react-router-bootstrap`. The types downloaded from npm does however not match the module itself. How can I reference my types file to reference this module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that only type definitions were loaded and not the module itself. Solved with `import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';`. You can read my answer here about custom types which was the reason for creating a custom type in the first place: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44046969/3850405