# error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module ''. '' implicitly has an 'any' type. TypeScript 2.0

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

I'm trying to use the module [react-image-gallery](https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery). However there are no types found for this package using npm.

`npm install @types/react-image-gallery` returs 404.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42505940/3850405) answer I tried to declare ImageGallery like this: `const ImageGallery = require('react-image-gallery');`

This gives no compiler warning but the application fails at runtime.

I can make everything work by setting `"noImplicitAny": false` in `tsconfig.json` but I do not wan't to disable this globally.

How can I mark my import as any?

I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
import ImageGallery: any from 'react-image-gallery';
import (ImageGallery as any) from 'react-image-gallery';
import { ImageGallery as any } from 'react-image-gallery';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Followed this guide here first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44046969/3850405

Added a new folder called `react-image-gallery` with a `index.d.ts` file. Content:

```
import * as React from "react";

export class ImageGallery extends React.Component<any, any> {

}

export default ImageGallery;
```

After this everything worked and the component could be imported normally with `import ImageGallery from 'react-image-gallery';`